# Ext3 file system became read-only and server reboots spontaneoulsy

Tags: linux, centos, drivers, hard-disk

We noticed ext3 file system in our CentOS 4.9 server became read-only.
We got the following error in `dmesg`:

> EXT3-fs: INFO: recovery required on readonly filesystem.
>     EXT3-fs: write access will be enabled during recovery.
>      kjournald starting.  Commit interval 5 seconds
>     EXT3-fs: recovery complete.

We also see the server restarting spontaneously every couple of days. Though the frequency of restart is not same.

How to determine any disk failure or the driver for hard disk is corrupted.
Driver for the sda device in our server is `/sys/bus/scsi/drivers/sd`.

Also how to find the root cause for the spontaneous reboot because we dont get any suspicious error in `dmesg` except that the ext3 file system is read-only.

Comment: Could there be temperature issues in the server room, the machine overheating? Also, perhaps try smartmontools and see what SMART diagnostic output you can get from the disk.

Comment: the [mount](http://linux.die.net/man/8/mount) command have an option `remount-ro` when there are errors on the filesystem (which could also explain random reboots), check your disk/filesystem ([fsck](http://linux.die.net/man/8/fsck)).

Comment: This part of the log isn't useful. What are the log entries that say that the filesystem has been remounted read-only? Do run a memory test, this is consistent with memory corruption: silently corrupting your data for a couple of days, then at some point a kernel pointer gets corrupted and the system reboots.

Comment: Thanks Giles. I couldn't find any logs that remounted the disk as read-only. I am planning to run a memory test to find faulty RAM. Can a faulty RAM corrupt the hard disk and remount it as read-only. If so any command or logs to find this.

Comment: dmesg also had a log saying "ext3_orphan_cleanup: deleting unreferenced inode".

This message indicates an abnormal system reboot created orphan inodes.During reboot "fsck" uitility found these orphan inodes and deletes these inodes.